# Alterar o campo text ao selecionar uma opção do dropdown

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte campo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"> 
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span id="search_concept">Filtrar por...</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="padding: 10px">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Nome</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Mês e ano</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Todos</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Nome" placeholder=" Filtrar por nome">

 <input type="date" class="form-control" name="Data" placeholder=" Filtrar por data">

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Todos" placeholder=" Filtro por todos os registros">

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="" placeholder=" Selecione o filtro ao lado">

            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-inverse" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
            </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#","");
        var concept = $(this).text();
        $('.search-panel span#search_concept').text(concept);
        $('.input-group #search_param').val(param);
    });
});
</script>
```

Gostaria de fazer com que ao selecionar a opção Mês e Ano, substituísse o campo Nome pelo campo da Data, se selecionar a opção Todos, alterar para o campo Todos e se não selecionar o filtro, aparecer uma mensagem pedindo para selecionar o filtro desejado. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Qual é o campo da Data?

Comment: Como seria essa substituição? Onde está o outro campo?

Comment: Olá pessoal. Desculpem. Fiz uma alteração no meu post.

Comment: No seu caso, vc esta com problema aonde exatamente? seria na hora de selecionar o item no dropdown? ou vc já consegue pegar o click do item corretamente?.

Se for o caso de pegar o click talvez vc possa usar "nth-child()"

"$('.search-panel .dropdown-menu li:nth-child(1)').click(function(e)"

Onde o numero dentro do parêntese do nth-child() é referente ao elemento da DOM, dai acredito que você possa verificar o click. Depois é só mudar o placeholder do input.

Comment: Olá Paulo. Na verdade não estou conseguindo fazer essa troca de campos, ou seja, cada opção aparecer seu respectivo campo.

Comment: Mas todos estão aparecendo ao mesmo tempo

Comment: Não seria o caso de você dar um display: none nós campos que você não quer que apareça e ao clicar por exemplo no botão mês, ele esconder os outros e mostrar só o mês.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução simples é adicionar a classe do Bootstrap `.d-none` aos campos que irão aparecer escondidos inicialmente, e acrescentar uma classe qualquer (coloquei `.f`) nos mesmos campos para você poder controlá-los.

Nos links do menu você coloca um dataset `data-f` com respectivos valores dos `name` dos campos. Assim, ao clicar em um link do menu, irá mostrar apenas o campo que possui o `name` igual ao `data-f` do link clicado, removendo a classe `d-none`:

```js
$(".search-panel .dropdown-menu a").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(".f").addClass("d-none");
   $("[name='"+this.dataset.f+"']").removeClass("d-none");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6"> 
     <div class="input-group">
         <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                 <span id="search_concept">Filtrar por...</span> <span class="caret"></span>
             </button>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="padding: 10px">
                 <li><a href="#" data-f="Nome"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Nome</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#" data-f="Data"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Mês e ano</a></li>
                 <li class="divider"></li>
                 <li><a href="#" data-f="Todos"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Todos</a></li>
             </ul>
         </div>
         <input type="text" class="form-control d-none f" name="Nome" placeholder=" Filtrar por nome">

          <input type="date" class="form-control d-none f" name="Data" placeholder=" Filtrar por data">
         
         <input type="text" class="form-control d-none f" name="Todos" placeholder=" Filtro por todos os registros">
         
         <input type="text" class="form-control f" placeholder=" Selecione o filtro ao lado">

         <span class="input-group-btn">
             <button class="btn btn-inverse" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
         </span>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

**Umas observações:**

Em vez de usar:

```
$('.search-panel .dropdown-menu').find('a')
```

Você pode usar:

```
$('.search-panel .dropdown-menu a')
```

É mais curto e evita usar um método a mais, o `.find()`.

Outra coisa é que não faz sentido usar o seletor:

```
'.search-panel span#search_concept'
```

Como um `id` deve ser único, basta ir direto a ele:

```
'#search_concept'
```

Comment: Perfeito Sam. Muito obrigado mais uma vez!

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seja isso que você deseja, eu peguei seu código e editei ele conforme sua necessitadade, espero por ter ajudado.

No código abaixo eu crio uma função para esconder os inputs e outra função que irá selecionar qual input vai aparecer e chamo a função no click dos botões dentro do dropdown, fazendo com que apareça o input do click escolhido:

```js
  function showSelectedInput(value){
    hideAll();
    if(value == 1) $('#nome').show();
    else if(value == 2) $('#data').show();
    else if(value == 3) $('#todos').show();
  }

  function hideAll(){
    $('#nome').hide();
    $('#data').hide();
    $('#todos').hide();
    $('#default').hide();
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-inverse dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <span id="search_concept">Filtrar por...</span> <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="padding: 10px">
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showSelectedInput(1)" ><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Nome</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showSelectedInput(2)" ><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Mês e ano</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showSelectedInput(3)" ><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i> Todos</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <input type="text" style="display:none" id="nome" class="form-control" name="Nome" placeholder=" Filtrar por nome">

      <input type="date" style="display:none" id="data" class="form-control" name="Data" placeholder=" Filtrar por data">

      <input type="text" style="display:none" id="todos" class="form-control" name="Todos" placeholder=" Filtro por todos os registros">

      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="default" name="" placeholder=" Selecione o filtro ao lado">

      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-inverse" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```